# JWT plugin setup with kong helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kong, kong-plugin

I have setup the kong gateway using helm chart and right now i need to install a JWT plugin for authenticating a service.

The flow is any DNS(example.anuj.com) > load Balancer (Kong-Proxy) > Istio LB > service.

I skipped few resources like Virtual service, gateway, Ingress.

Now, i have a requirement to install JWT plugin and get the request validated, so i am unable to find the steps to get it done via Helm chart, like what changes needs to be done on values.yaml file, is there any more resource required for this?

Plz help.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to install the **Plugin**, if it's already part of **Default** **Image** nothing to worry about then.

Install Plugin to Kong Docker image for ref : https://faun.pub/building-kong-custom-docker-image-add-a-customized-kong-plugin-2157a381d7fd

Once plugin is installed in **Container Image** you can enable it just by mentioning it in **Env** **var**.

**Env var detail**

Where bundled mean i guess default and followed by you have added

```
- name: KONG_PLUGINS
  value: bundled,myplugin
```